# How to inherit variables with double inheritance?

Tags: python, variables, inheritance

I want to inherit variables.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
class A(ABC):

   #var 

   def __init__(self):
      self.__var = 1

   def getVar(self):
      return self.__var

   def changeVar(self, k):
      self.__var = k


class B(A):
   def __init__(self):
      pass

class C(B):
   def __init__(self, var):
      super().changeVar(var)

c = C(1) #var = 1
c2 = C(2) #var = 2
print(c.getVar()) #print 1
c.changeVar(2) #change to 2
```

Basically I want to inherit and change variables just like if they would be declared in class `A`. Any way to do that in a simple not complicated way?
And variables for `c` and `c2` wouldn't be connected in any way, what I mean by that is if I change one variable in `c` then in `c2` would not change.

Comment: Can you provide your expect usage?

Comment: The point of this is that class B will have function which will also use getVar() and changeVar() and class C also. So every object of class C should have variables that are declared in class A. This is how i have it in Java, the declarations in class A and then i inherit them. and i can access these variables in class B and C using the functions that are in A

Comment: `c.__var` is *only* defined by `A.changeVar`, since you never invoke `A.__init__` at any point. Each `__init__` method should be calling `super().__init__` to ensure the instance is being properly initialized.

Comment: If `B.__init__` isn't doing anything else, you don't need to define it at all.

Comment: would this be correct? in C __init__ - super(B, self).__init__() and then in B __init__ - super(A, self).__init__() and then in A __init__ variables would be just initialized

Comment: As an aside, stop writing pointless getters and setter, and don't use double-undercore name mangling unless you really need it